# Hibernate Unknown entity exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting unknown entity exception below is the stack trace

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.entities.Users
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1145)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1358)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:683)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:675)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:671)
    at com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.business.UsersDAOImpl.addUser(UsersDAOImpl.java:28)
    at com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.actions.RegisterAction.execute(RegisterAction.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilt
INFO:   er(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I am not using spring and don't want to use.
This is users class

```
package com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Cacheable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;


/**
 *
 * @author sabertooth
 */
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@org.hibernate.annotations.SelectBeforeUpdate
public class Users implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long uid;


    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @Column(length = 512)
    private String activation;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date joined;

    public Date getJoined() {
        return joined;
    }

    public void setJoined() {
        joined = new Date();
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")

    private Collection<Files> files=new ArrayList<Files>();

    public long getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lasttName) {
        this.lastName = lasttName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getActivation() {
        return activation;
    }

    public void setActivation(String activation) {
        this.activation = activation;
    }

    public Collection<Files> getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    public void setFiles(Collection<Files> files) {
        this.files = files;
    }

}
```

This is hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ossoc</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">deflection</property>
    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
    <!-- second-level cache  -->
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</property>
    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <!-- <property name="show_sql">true</property> -->
    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
    <mapping class="com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.entities.Users" file="" jar="" package="" resource=""/>
    <mapping class="com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.entities.Files"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am using `import javax.persistence.Entity;` and also mapping my entity classes in `hibernate.cfg.xml` file then why am I getting this exception.

I am using ServletContextListener to get session factory below is the code
Any help would be highly appreciated. Stuck in this problem from a long time.

```
package com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.interceptors;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;


public class HibernateListener implements ServletContextListener{
    private Configuration config;
    private SessionFactory sf;
    private static Class clazz = HibernateListener.class;

    public static final String KEY_NAME = clazz.getName();

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    if(sf!=null)
        {
            sf.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

        try 
        {
            config = new Configuration();

            config.configure();
            ServiceRegistry sr = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
            sf = config.buildSessionFactory(sr);  
            event.getServletContext().setAttribute(KEY_NAME, sf);
        } 
        catch (HibernateException e) 
        {

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Class to open session

```
package com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.util;

import com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.interceptors.HibernateListener;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class DataSource {
    private SessionFactory sf;

    private Session session;



    public Session getSession(){
        if(session==null)
        {
            createSession();
        }
        return session;
    }

    private void createSession(){
        sf = (SessionFactory) ServletActionContext.getServletContext()
                     .getAttribute(HibernateListener.KEY_NAME);
        session=sf.openSession();
    }

}
```

Comment: if I were you, I would make sure this line is valid <mapping class="com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.entities.Users" file="" jar="" package="" resource=""/>. I am not exactly sure but I have always seen table name mentioned inside the mapping .

Comment: *"I am not using spring and don't want to use."* Are you happy with Struts2 container?

Comment: @RomanC I am learning and I want to learn these before jumping to spring

Comment: @Ashish I run this same code in other program in main method and it works fine.

Comment: did u find a solution?

Comment: if you are using one framework with another look up the integration  solution.

Comment: @Ashish No any help..

Comment: lemme know if the solution i posted work for you. I think you need to add the annotated class in your servletcontext and thats what I did here.

Comment: @Ashish I tried your solution but I am getting 
java.lang.NullPointerException
I check and find out that SessionFatory object is null.
SessionFactory is not initialized

Comment: I also noticed that you are not opening any session after building a session factory.

Comment: @Ashish I am putting my sessionfactory object in Servletcontext and asseing that servlet context in some other class to open session.

Comment: your datasource class looks fine. Now the issue is to find out why your sessionFactory is null. try commenting out the ServiceRegistry line and remove 'sr' from buildSessionFactory().

Comment: @Ashish no effect same NullPointerException 
Its been 2 days tring to resolve this issue but no luck

Comment: if somehow you could send me the zipped version of whatever you have done so far, I will fix it. besided you dont have enough reputation to move this over to chat

Comment: @Ashish I would be more than happy if u could help me.
I tries to use spring DI but getting some exception below are two links get zip from those links

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3jixQR0Mr9aM0FRZW1TZTQ3ckk/edit?usp=sharing
ossoc spring DI
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3jixQR0Mr9aeVRxNl9vcWtCY1U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: if you dont see <pluginManagement> right inside <build> in your pom.xml, please add it  and close it before </build>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something like this should work for ya.

```
package com.riteshsangwan.ossoc.interceptors;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;


public class HibernateListener implements ServletContextListener{
   private AnnotationConfiguration config;
   private SessionFactory sf;
   private static Class clazz = HibernateListener.class;

   public static final String KEY_NAME = clazz.getName();

   @Override
   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    if(sf!=null)
      {
        sf.close();
      }
    }

   @Override
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

    try 
    {
        config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
        config.addAnnotatedClass(Users.class);
        ServiceRegistry sr = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
        sf = config.configure().buildSessionFactory(sr);  
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute(KEY_NAME, sf);
    } 
    catch (HibernateException e) 
    {

    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package Test;

import java.util.EnumSet;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.TargetType;
import org.junit.Test;

import Entity.Users;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
         try {
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( serviceRegistry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction=session.beginTransaction();
        Users users=new Users();
        users.setId(2);
        session.save(users);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
         }catch(Throwable th){
                System.err.println("Init SessionFactory creation failed" );
                System.err.println(th);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(th);
         }finally {

        }
    }


}
```

I use hibernate5.1 ，it`s OK.

Answer (score 0):

To solve **Hibernate Unknown Entity** exception, you should check the following:

1. Check if import the right package: `import javax.persistence.Entity;`
2. Check the `mapping-class` or `mapping-resource` in `hibernate.cfg.xml`
3. For some versions of `hibernate`, it may not be able to initialize `SessionFactory` in the above way. Try this code:

   `SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();`

In the above case, the third way may work.